# How can I get a count of the optional arguments with xparse?

Tags: macros, environments, xparse, environment-variables

## Question

Is it possible to get and store a count of the optional arguments actually passed to an `xparse` declare argument/environment?

## Purpose

*Regardless of the number of arguments provided (arbitrary depending on situation), I want to do something very specific with the last one given.* Because this is a variable number, I need to retrieve the count of arguments given and use that combined with `#` to do something with that variable.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}} % 10 optional args
{startcode}
{endcode}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mycom}{O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}O{}}{% 10 optional args
}%

\begin{document}

\mycom[a][b][c] % Count 3
% Do something special with #3

\begin{myenv}[a][b][c][d] % Count 4
% Do something special with #4
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply check from the end if the optional argument has no value. But are you sure that a command with so many arguments is senseful?  I avoid more then two arguments.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That test is not robust enough. It does not work when working with an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: How can the number be arbitrary in the definition? Your example shows 10 arguments, so this is the maximum.

Comment: @macmadness86 You can't have more than nine arguments (like in all TeX macros). In any case, since the arguments would start from the beginning `\IfValueTF{#9}{9 arguments}{\IfValueTF{#8}{8 arguments}{..}}` would work. By the way, why not declare the last one as `m` mandatory, and the eight before as  `o`? `\foo[a][b][c][d]{e}`.

Comment: @Manuel I knew about the `\IfValueTF` but I was hoping for a "cleaner" solution (less code). I think just making the ninth argument mandatory is a good idea and should work for my purposes! I did not know about the maximum number of arguments.

Comment: @Manuel Ok oops, the answer to your question about just declaring the last arg `m` is that I still do not know whether `m`=`#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,` or `#9`.

Comment: @macmadness86 If it's mandatory, it's the last one, so you know what argument you have to do the special thing to. I'm not really sure what your intentions are: surely this syntax is very clumsy and error prone.

Comment: @egreg Please consider my last comment. to Manuel. How do I know which number represents the last variable if the user can sometimes use 3 args (last=#3), sometimes 8 (last=#8)? Thats a pretty general judgement right there (about this syntax being clumsy), by the way.

Comment: using more than two optional arguments is a horrible user interface, can you not use a comma separated list? `\foo[a,b,c,d,e,f]` expl3 then makes it easy to count the list, iterate over it, select the last etc.

Comment: Isn't this all subject that `xparse` (or even the traditional way) can't know which of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 optional arguments is really the one under supervision? Does `\foo[This][is]` mean `This` is the 1st or may be the 5th opt. argument?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Putting aside that this doesn't really answer the question of getting an argument count, I do appreciate that you're trying to help me create a more efficient way of doing this. The actual use is to create a specially formatted form. I need to isolate the arguments to insert them in specific places. Another criterion is to keep the code readable. Being able to put argument inputs on separate lines is key. The other option is to create horrible looking tables of this information (I am trying to provide a better option)

Comment: sure but `[][][]` is the _wrong_ input syntax for that (irrespective of coding and efficiency issues)

Comment: `xparse` is meant for defining LaTeX2e-like interface: it's not a general 'parse some input' set up. I wonder if you might be better with a delimited argument, so `\foo a b c d e\stop` or similar (where `\stop` may be defined naturally by your real use case).

Comment: @macmadness86 What do you mean? If you have `{oooooooom}` you ALWAYS have `#9` as the mandatory argument. If you use `\foo[a]{b}` then `#1` is `a` and `#9` is `b` (the rest are “empty”). If you have `\foo[a][b][c][d]{e}` then `#1`–`#4` are `a`–`d` and `#9` is `e` (the rest are “empty”). I don't see what's the problem. In any case, I agree, this is not the optimal solution (more than 2 or 4 arguments is *really* a bad sign for a “user macro”).

Comment: @Manuel Ah I did not know that #9 would *always* be the mandatory argument. Thank you for that information.

Comment: Not sure why the question was closed as unclear. It's arguable if the requested syntax is ideal, but the actual question seems clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use repeated `[]` arguments in this way. use a comma separated list for an arbitrary argument syntax.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{O{}} 
{\doargs:n{#1}}
{}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mycom}{O{}}{
\doargs:n{#1}
}%
\clist_new:N\arglist

\cs_new_protected:Nn\doargs:n{{
\clist_set:Nn\arglist{#1}
[there ~are ~\clist_count:N\arglist{} ~ arguments]
[the ~last ~one ~is ~\clist_item:Nn\arglist{\clist_count:N\arglist}]
}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mycom[a,b,c] % Count 3
% Do something special with #3

\begin{myenv}[a,b,c,d] % Count 4
% Do something special with #4
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. Do you think you should show me how to iterate the parameters. e.g. My idea: user command variant and turn this: `\noindent\clist_item:Nn\arglist{1},~\clist_item:Nn\arglist{2},~\clist_item:Nn\arglist{3},~\clist_item:Nn\arglist{4}\par` into a loop. Each item can be put into a tabular using the trick you showed me `\tabular{l{\arglist{\clist_count:N\arglist}}}` (num of cols determined by clist_count). Each item (`\clist_item:Nn\arglist{itemStep}`) can be followed by `&` until column step=`clist_count:N\arglist` then a `\\` is inserted. +1Automation

Comment: @macmadness86 That's a new question really, but see `texdoc interface3` from page 120 there are 10 pages of interesting functions you can apply to clists.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip. I will hop to it. Just to clarify, this code with the ExplSyntaxOn/Off is fully backwards compatible?

Comment: @macmadness86 backwards compatible with what? the only code there is the definition of a new command.

Comment: I meant, can I compile this document on a machine with an older version of LaTeX, just by installing the `expl3` package. I think I already found my answer though, and the answer is yes.