# How can I use the ampersand (&) as a delineator for tabs in LaTeX3 (expl3)/xparse syntax?

Tags: tables, latex3, xparse, active-characters

This idea evolved from the question: [How can I get a count of the optional arguments with xparse?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243401/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-the-optional-arguments-with-xparse)

## Problem

I cannot get the ampersand to function as a delineator (for tab stops) inside the `\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mygroup}`. I thought maybe I should be looking here: [How can I give active characters definitions with expl3?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184753/how-can-i-give-active-characters-definitions-with-expl3). I am quite sure what the issue is, because the ampersand works in the `DeclareDocumentEnvironment{mytab}{O{}}`.

**Working (not really, just does not crash when typesetting):** `\doargs:n{#1} &  \\ % interestingly, this ampersand does not crash typesetting.`

**Not working:** `{\clist_item:Nn \arglist {##1}\&} % added backslash to & for debugging`

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn % based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243442/13552
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{mytab}{O{}}%
{\noindent\begin{tabular}{*{50}{l}}}
{\end{tabular}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mygroup}{O{}m}{
\doargs:n{#1} &  \\ % interestingly, this ampersand does not crash typesetting.
\multicolumn{\clist_count:N \arglist}{l}{\indent\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent\relax}{{\small\textit{#2}}}} \\%[\baselineskip]
}%
\clist_new:N\arglist
\cs_new_protected:Nn\doargs:n{{%
\clist_set:Nn\arglist{#1}%
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1}{\clist_count:N \arglist}
    {\clist_item:Nn \arglist {##1}\&} % added backslash to & for debugging
}}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{mytab}
\mygroup[
Special 1,
ID 1,
A,
B]
{Some nice long description.}

\mygroup[
Special 2,
ID 2,
A,
B]
{Some nice long description.}

\mygroup[
Special 3,
ID 3,
A,
B]
{Some nice long description.}
\end{mytab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tabular cells are groups. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3108/use-column-separator-ampersand-inside-newenvironment/3110#3110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to start a loop in a cell, ending it in another one. This can't work, because alignment cells form groups.

You want to use `\clist_use:Nn`

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{mytab}{O{}}
  {\begin{tabular}{*{50}{l}}}
  {\end{tabular}}

\clist_new:N \g_macmadness_mygroup_items_clist

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mygroup}{O{}m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_macmadness_mygroup_items_clist { #1 }
  \clist_use:Nn \g_macmadness_mygroup_items_clist { & } \\
  \multicolumn{ 50 } {@{}l@{}}
   {
    \hspace{\parindent}
    \parbox{\dim_eval:n { \textwidth-\parindent } } {\small\itshape #2}
   }
   \\[\normalbaselineskip]
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{mytab}
\mygroup[
Special 1,
ID 1,
A,
B]
{Some nice long description.}

\mygroup[
Special 2,
ID 2,
A,
B]
{Some nice long description.}

\mygroup[
Special 3,
ID 3,
A,
B]
{Some nice long description.}
\end{mytab}

\end{document}
```

This expands the whole list with the stated separator, so TeX won't see `&` during the process, but only when it has ended.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I seem to loose flexibility at every turn due to the simplicity of MWEs. I need to be able to use `\int_step_inline:nnnn{2}{1}{\clist_count:N \g_macmadness_mygroup_items_clist}`. I am going to have item 1 be left-aligned and the rest be right-aligned in the tabular. (Also, I will be using longtable, but I think that is superfluous here)

Comment: Actually, I do not even want to simplify it that much. I just need to be able to access each item individually. Therefore, `\clist_use` isn't really an option, I think.

Comment: @macmadness86 I can't read in your mind.

Comment: You say that often, I noticed. This is why I explicitly said what I want above. Your solution is quite restrictive (you cannot isolate items in the loop), which is why I left it unanswered for the time being. Perhaps in time it will be the best answer. I am already looking into other solutions (ways of spreading information automatically across a page horizontally  where widths are calculated automatically based on the number of args other than tab stops so that I can use the `int_step_inline` iterator).

Comment: @macmadness86 If you want to use an `\int_step_inline:nnnn` loop, you have to builld a token list step by step and deliver it only at the end.