# Column delimiter in a macro to render rows for tabularray

Tags: macros, latex3, tabularray

I'm trying to programmatically typeset rows inside a `tblr` table (from `tabularray`), but I'm unable to solve a `Misplaced alignment tab character &` error.

This minimal example reproduces my exact situation, including the structure of the macro calls I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tabularray}

\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn

  \seq_new:N \entries_seq

  \NewDocumentCommand { \entry } { m m m } {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \entries_seq { { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
  }

  \cs_new:Nn \make_row:nnn {
    % NOTE: this macro will also contain some complex logic for rendering the cells content
    #1 & #2 & #3 \\
  }

  \NewDocumentEnvironment { mytblr } {} {} {
    \begin{tblr}{lll}
      A & B & C \\
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \entries_seq { \make_row:nnn ##1 }
      X & Y & Z \\
    \end{tblr}
  }

  \ExplSyntaxOff

  \begin{mytblr}
    \entry{1}{2}{3}
    \entry{4}{5}{6}
  \end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

This minimal example reproduces just the error, disregarding the current organisation of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn

    \cs_new:Nn \make_test_row: {
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
    }

    \begin{tblr}{lll}
      \make_test_row:
    \end{tblr}

  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I'm aware of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338918/82186 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243627/82186 but `tabularray` seems to be introducing some difference I can't pinpoint (In fact those solutions don't work replacing `tabular` with `tblr`).

It might be enough to solve the problem just on the shorter example to clarify the technique I need to use, but I included the longer example because that's the situation where I'll need to use it.

Comment: Maybe this link could help you: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/18

Comment: Thanks for the tip @L.J.R. ! The syntax in the issue you linked is spot-on, but my `\make_row` will have some pretty complex logic to produce the cells content, so it's not just a matter of separating presentation. Perhaps https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/23#issuecomment-874011259 could be a better starting point. I'll try to fiddle a bit with that.

Comment: I have added `expand` option for expanding specified macro:  https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/18#issuecomment-877731628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[In your examples you did not obey all expl3-conventions for naming control sequences.

In my coding-examples I renamed things to fit the conventions.]*

In your example the `\entry`-macro is used for accumulating things within a sequence-variable. You use it within the `mytblr`-environment. At the end of that environment the things stored in the variable are to be nested inside a `tblr`-environment. You did not specify the desired behavior in case the `mytblr`-environment contains something other than calls to the `\entry`-macro.

E.g., you didn't specify the desired output for

```latex
 \begin{mytblr}
    \entry{1}{2}{3}%
    A&B&C\\
    \entry{4}{5}{6}%
  \end{mytblr}
```

where `A&B&C\\` will not be turned into an element of the sequence-variable and therefore attempting to typeset takes place immediately and outside the `tblr`-environment.

As you did not specify this I assume that instances of your `mytblr`-environment only contain calls to `\entry` and nothing else.

The `tblr`-environment of the package **tabularray** needs its body to be expanded.

Thus although it is said that with expl3-stuff you don't need to care about expansion-issues, you have to ensure that stuff is passed to the `tblr`-environment expanded.

You use a sequence-variable `\entries_seq` while in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) I didn't find any expandable function documented for mapping function-calls to the items of a sequence-variable in a way where you can obtain the entire sequence of function-calls in one go without further expansion-trickery.

(In expansion-contexts the difference between
`\map{{A}{B}{C}}{\thing}` yielding `\thing{A}\map{{B}{C}}{\thing}`
and
`\map{{A}{B}{C}}{\thing}` in one go yielding `\thing{A}\thing{B}\thing{C}`
is important.
Seems with expl3-mapping-functions you get something like the further.
You also may need to cope with controlling the level of expansion of `\thing`.)

You can work around this, e.g., by mapping the content of the sequence-variable `\l__MyModule_entries_seq` to a token-list-variable `\l__MyModule_entries_tl`, hereby prepending `\__MyModule_MakeRow:nnn` to each element of the sequence and once expanding that command.

After mapping, via `\use_ii_i:nn` you exchange the content of the token-list-variable `\l__MyModule_entries_tl` with the tokens `\begin{tblr}{lll} A & B & C \\`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tabularray}

  \ExplSyntaxOn

  % Probably you can use one of the scratch-variables \l_tmpa_seq / \l_tmpb_seq  instead:
  \seq_new:N \l__MyModule_entries_seq
  % Probably you can use one of the scratch-variables \l_tmpa_tl / \l_tmpb_tl  instead:
  \tl_new:N \l__MyModule_entries_tl

  \NewDocumentCommand { \entry } { m m m } {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__MyModule_entries_seq { { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
  }

  \cs_new:Nn \__MyModule_MakeRow:nnn {
    % NOTE: this macro will also contain some complex logic for rendering the cells content
    #1 & #2 & #3 \\
  }

  % \cs_new:Nn \use_ii_i:nn { #2 #1 }

  \NewDocumentEnvironment { mytblr } {} {\seq_clear:N \l__MyModule_entries_seq} {
    \tl_clear:N \l__MyModule_entries_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__MyModule_entries_seq {  \tl_put_right:No \l__MyModule_entries_tl {\__MyModule_MakeRow:nnn ##1} }
    \exp_args:NV \use_ii_i:nn  { \l__MyModule_entries_tl }
    { \begin{tblr}{lll}
        A & B & C \\  }
      X & Y & Z \\
    \end{tblr}
  }

  \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{mytblr}%
    \entry{1}{2}{3}%
    \entry{4}{5}{6}%
  \end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

Actually this is unnecessarily complicated. You can do without a sequence-variable, using only a token-list-variable:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tabularray}

  \ExplSyntaxOn

  % Probably you can use one of the scratch-variables \l_tmpa_tl / \l_tmpb_tl  instead:
  \tl_new:N \l__MyModule_entries_tl


  \NewDocumentCommand { \entry } { m m m } {
    \tl_put_right:No \l__MyModule_entries_tl {\__MyModule_MakeRow:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
  }

  \cs_new:Nn \__MyModule_MakeRow:nnn {
    % NOTE: this macro will also contain some complex logic for rendering the cells content
    #1 & #2 & #3 \\
  }

  % \cs_new:Nn \use_ii_i:nn { #2 #1 }

  \NewDocumentEnvironment { mytblr } {} {\tl_clear:N \l__MyModule_entries_tl} {
    \exp_args:NV \use_ii_i:nn { \l__MyModule_entries_tl }
    { \begin{tblr}{lll}
        A & B & C \\  }
      X & Y & Z \\
    \end{tblr}
  }

  \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{mytblr}%
    \entry{1}{2}{3}%
    \entry{4}{5}{6}%
  \end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

I just realized: In expl3 release 2019-08-30 `\seq_map_tokens:Nn` was introdcuced.

Using this you can do with a sequence-variable only, no need for a token-list-variable:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularray}

  \ExplSyntaxOn

  % Probably you can use one of the scratch-variables \l_tmpa_seq / \l_tmpb_seq  instead:
  \seq_new:N \l__MyModule_entries_seq

  \cs_new:Nn \MyModule_JoinArgsAndCallExpNot:Nnnn {
     % #1 some \exp_args...-command to be applied to #2#4#3
     % #2 tokens to prepend to element of sequence
     % #3 tokens to append to element of sequence
     % #4 element of sequence
     #1 \exp_not:n {#2#4#3}
  }

  \NewDocumentCommand { \entry } { m m m } {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__MyModule_entries_seq { { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
  }

  \cs_new:Nn \__MyModule_MakeRow:nnn {
    % NOTE: this macro will also contain some complex logic for rendering the cells content
    #1 & #2 & #3 \\
  }

  % \cs_new:Nn \use_ii_i:nn { #2 #1 }

  \NewDocumentEnvironment { mytblr } {} {\seq_clear:N \l__MyModule_entries_seq} {
    \exp_args:Nx \use_ii_i:nn  { 
      \seq_map_tokens:Nn  \l__MyModule_entries_seq { \MyModule_JoinArgsAndCallExpNot:Nnnn \exp_args:No {\__MyModule_MakeRow:nnn} {} }
    }{ \begin{tblr}{lll}
        A & B & C \\  }
      X & Y & Z \\
    \end{tblr}
  }

  \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{mytblr}%
    \entry{1}{2}{3}%
    \entry{4}{5}{6}%
  \end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

With the example above I used **o**-expansion on purpose:

[expl3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) says:

> **o** One-level-expanded token or braced token list.
> This means that the argument is expanded one level, as by `\expandafter`, and the expansion is passed to the function as a braced token list. Note that if the original argument is a braced token list then only the first token in that list is expanded. In general, using **V** should be preferred to using **o** for simple variable retrieval

---

With all these examples the output is:

[image]

---

These examples are just a starting-point.

The modifications needed depend on the implications of your comment about `\make_row:nnn`:

> % NOTE: this macro will also contain some complex logic for rendering the cells content

In any case the chain of processing and expanding things must work out in a way where the content of the token-list variable, which is to be passed behind the sequence `\begin{tblr}{lll} A & B & C \\`,  consists of a sequence of tokens expanded as far as needed with the body of the `tblr`-environment.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use an expandable mapping, so `\seq_map_function:NN`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \pb_mytblr_entries_seq

\NewDocumentCommand { \entry } { m m m }
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \pb_mytblr_entries_seq { { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \pb_mytblr_make_row:n
 {
  \pb_mytblr_make_row:nnn #1
 }

\cs_new:Nn \pb_mytblr_make_row:nnn
 {
  % NOTE: this macro will also contain some complex logic for rendering the cells content
  #1 & #2 & #3 \\
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { mytblr } {}
 {
  % do nothing at the beginning
 } 
 {
  \use:e
   {
    \exp_not:N \begin{tblr}{lll}
    A & B & C \\
    \seq_map_function:NN \pb_mytblr_entries_seq \pb_mytblr_make_row:n
    X & Y & Z \\
    \exp_not:N \end{tblr}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{mytblr}
    \entry{1}{2}{3}
    \entry{4}{5}{6}
  \end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

Please, stick with the recommended naming scheme.

[image]